# Add column Heroku database

Tags: python, django, database, heroku

Goodnight.

I have a project done in Python and Django and today I added one more Model Table and added a column manually and it worked in the development environment.

But when deploying to Heroku , Heroku cannot find this manually created column and returns this error "column does not exist" .

How do I manually add a column to the Heroku database?

Comment: Are you using Migrations to manage and propagate changes that you make to your schema? You can read about them in the Django docs: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/migrations/ also, if you're looking for an alternative place to deploy your project given the end of Heroku's free tier, check out the Django quickstart on Render (the company I work for) https://render.com/docs/deploy-django

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Heroku cannot find this manually created column

Of course it can't. You created it on another database.

Manually modifying your database schema is a bad idea, especially if you're using a framework like Django that has database migrations built in. Modify your models and generate a migration with `python manage.py makemigrations`, or create a migration manually. Test the migration and commit it when you're happy with it.

Then push do Heroku and run your migrations there by running `heroku run python manage.py migrate`. Some users like to set this as a [release task](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/release-phase#specifying-release-phase-tasks) so it runs automatically.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure you should be managing your tables manually but if you must do it manually and you're using [Heroku Postgres](https://devcenter.heroku.com/categories/heroku-postgres), you can use the [Heroku CLI](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-cli) to open a `psql` session:

```bash
heroku pg:psql
```

Note you will need PostgreSQL installed locally. See [docs](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/managing-heroku-postgres-using-cli#pg-psql) for more details.